# RDS to S3 using pg_dump directly (without intermediary)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-rds

It's possible run pg_dump in the RDS or in a S3 (without using a intermediary like ec2 to execute the command)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should be able to access it as long as your db security group allows external access to port 5432 (default for postgres). Then you can just run:

```
pg_dump -h <database_host> -U <username> <database>
```

Keep in mind that your connection will not be encrypted.

AFAIK, there is no interface in AWS between RDS and S3, so you would have to use an intermediary to transfer the data to S3.

Comment: Whenever possible, run this stuff from an EC2 instance inside of AWS - Way faster, more secure (opening DB to internet = bad) and no outbound data costs.  Much faster to upload to S3 as well.

Answer (score 17):

The AWS CLI added support for [uploads from stdin](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/pull/903), so you now have the option of doing something like this:

```
pg_dump ...dbargs... | aws s3 cp - s3://my-bucket/backup-$(date "+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S")
```

It's not ideal, as you are streaming to your local machine and then into s3 - but it's at least a single command.